# How to call a function from controller class python?

Tags: function, controller, odoo

Help guys, 
this is my controller class function:

```
class MyController(http.Controller):
    @http.route(["/myPath/"], type='http', auth="public", website=True)
    def myfucntion(self):
        -- something ---
```

Here is my model:

```
class SaleOrderLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = "sale.order.line"
```

How to call function from controller class?
Please, help me. I need any idea, any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your function returns, but something like this should work

```
return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_url',
        'url': '/myPath/,
        'target': 'new',
    }
```

Comment: Hello , my function have return, I don't understand how to call in my model. Do you have example.

Comment: how i told you, with that return

Comment: return {'day_off': day_off,
                'day_of_limit': day_of_limit}

Answer (score 0):

Try something similar to this:

```
class MyController(http.Controller):
    @http.route(["/myPath/"], type='http', auth="public", website=True)
    def myfucntion(self):
        http.request.env['sale.order.line'].my_method()
```